# How can I copy text from a website and use it in my own HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, copy

I am making a website to look for prices of flights. Every time that I load my HTML file I have to copy the prices from another website that is not mine and insert them in my HTML file.

The source code of the other website indicates that the tag that I am looking for is a span tag, like `<span class="amount price-amount">250</span>`

So the question is: How can I copy or extract that info and use it or insert it in my HTML file?

I would like to solve it using HTML, CSS, JavaScript and/or Bootstrap.

Comment: Have you checked the other websites for a developers API page? This could save you a lot of work and time.

Comment: I haven't personally done this, but looks like `import.io` might be a good option. Check it out here: https://import.io/advanced-data-platform

Comment: import.io is a great idea. Or you need a server side script to load the page and import data. Client-side like javascript as you said are not allowed to get content from other page, just if they set "cross-domain" access, you can check but they probably didn't.

Comment: @NewToJS. I have never use an API. That website has an API but I have no idea how to use it. I prefer to solve it in other way by now and then look info about APIs.

Comment: @robysottini you can use page stripping, take a look at my answer

Comment: @HenriqueKieckbusch, what do you mean by server side script? I don't have access to the server because the website is not mine, so I can't execute a script on the server. Am I correct?

Comment: @robysottini If the website offer an API i could recommend using it. If you really want the information from the website it's always worth taking the time to learn how to use it. If you spend 5 minutes reading that page, look for sample code, most API's come with sample code for you to learn from.

Comment: I mean, your own website can access the other website and import data from time to time. You can use server-side scripts like: php... they will be like robots doing the same thing you did so far. Any server-side script has access to load other pages and get content. Javascript (a client-sided script) can do that too (using the examples the 2 answers above), but the other website needs to allow that by a config called "cross-domain".  Server-sided scripts you will have all that automatic. if you want to make something handled you can use the import.io app, is really good too to steal data.

Answer (score 2):

## Client-Side Webscraping

You do this using *page stripping*. At least that's what I call it. A basic example is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {

        var doc = document.createElement('div');
        doc.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        var elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('*'),
        prices = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {

            if ((elems[i].getAttribute('class')||'').indexOf('price-amount') > -1 && (elems[i].getAttribute('class')||'').indexOf('amount') > -1) {
                prices.push(elems[i].innerHTML);
            }

        }
    }
};
xhr.open('GET', 'airlinesite.com/path/to/page', true);
xhr.send();
```

This will get the HTML from `airlinesite.com/path/to/page`. Then it will get all the elements. Loop through them. If it has a class `amount` and `price-amount`, it will store it's value in an Array. The values will be stored in `prices`.

**For this, the target domain must have CORS, which it probably does**

Answer (score 1):

Use a web-scraper; I recommend `request` and `cheerio`. This assumes you have `Node JS` and know how to install packages.
Here's a simple sample code:

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request(this.url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // body is the scraped html
        $ = cheerio.load(arg); // the jQuery-like selector
        var price = $('span.price-amount').text(); // the price you want. Use the selector accordingly.
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

use inspect element, do this by right clicking and click inspect element. then there will be a box with and arrow pointing into in the top left corner, this is the search click it. Then select what part you want on the page, then it will load it, that way you can just copy and paste it.

Comment: Prices change, do you really expect robysottini to use inspect element each time the site updates their prices? This would be a waste of time and no doubt will need to be done for multiple sites.